# Accessing the process / environment from a grunt template

Tags: javascript, templates, underscore.js, gruntjs

I have some code in a grunt.js file which is working with 0.3 but breaks on 0.4:

```
{
    dest: '<%= process.env.DEST %>/index.html'
}
```

In 0.3 process is defined and so I can access variables defined in the environment inside the template when I am e.g. passing file paths to other plugins.

Is there an alternative approach to this which will work in 0.4? Or a way to put a breakpoint in while the template is rendering so that I can see what variables are available?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

[The default data is the config object](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.config). You can add the environment variable to the config object or just use it directly.

```
grunt.initConfig({
    destination: process.env.DEST,
    task: {
        target: {
            dest: '<%= destination %>/index.html'
        }
    },
});
```

or

```
grunt.initConfig({
    task: {
        target: {
            dest: process.env.DEST + '/index.html'
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the very clear answer - that's demystified something that had me confused!

Comment: Note that the documentation @SindreSorhus mentions has moved to http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.config.

Answer (score 0):

That's a great straight forward answer by Sindre. Alternatively you can do (use the grunt-env plugin: https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-env )-

```
grunt.initConfig({
    env : {
        test : {
            DEST : 'testDEST'
        },
        dev : {
            DEST : 'devDEST'
        },
        qa : {
            DEST : 'qaDEST'
        },
        prod : {
            DEST : 'prodDEST'
        }
    }

});


grunt.registerTask('setenvs', 'Set environment variables', function() {
    grunt.config('ENVS', process.env);
});
```

and then use

```
{
    dest: '<%= ENVS.DEST %>/index.html'
}
```

Your task would be -

```
    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'env:dev',
        'setenvs'
        'yourTask'
    ]);
```

Proposed alternative approach just so that you can use `<%= ... %>` and you don't have to hardcode it in initConfig.  Target for env you can take as input from user and pass it to env.

Comment: Is is possible to load environment variables from files with grunt-env, right? how can you access them? I'm currently failing to do that. I would like to access a .env file that I'm already using with webpack. Is it possible? Thx!