# gruntjs environment variables. Are there any available?

Tags: gruntjs

Is there a list of variables, that I can use in my grunt config files? Something which I know from maven like project.build.dir..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing the process / environment from a grunt template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989978/accessing-the-process-environment-from-a-grunt-template)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several things may be of help to you.

1 - You can access any of the operating system's environment variables via `process.environment`, for example:

```
console.log( process.env.HOME );
```

2 - The typical approach to package-level information is to read it from package.json via the `grunt.initConfig` method. See the [Project and Task Configuration Section](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started#project-and-task-configuration) of the Getting Started Guid.

3 - Since the convention is to have Gruntfile.js in the root of your project, all the other paths are relative to this, so when you have something like this in your task configuration, it's all relative to Gruntfile

```
    files: {
      src: './Libraries/Foo/foo.js'
    }
```