# How to check ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT in Grunt?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, asp.net-core, environment-variables

I am using ASP.NET Core with [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/). I need to check the project environment. How can I do something like this?

```
if(ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT === 'Production')
{
  //do something
}
else 
{
  //do something
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing the process / environment from a grunt template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989978/accessing-the-process-environment-from-a-grunt-template)

Comment: i need something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31228947/how-to-determine-the-asp-net-core-environment-in-my-gulpfile-js